# Grouping numerical values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my `Dataframe` I have one column with numeric values, let say - distance. I want to find out which group of distance (range) have the biggest number of records (rows).

Doing simple:
`df.distance.count_values()` returns:

```
74         1
90         1
94         1
893        1
889        1
885        1
877        1
833        1
122        1
545        1
```

What I want to achieve is something like buckets from histogram, so I am expecting output like this:

```
900         4 #all values < 900 and > 850
100         3
150         1
550         1
850         1
```

The one approach I've figured out so far, but I don't think is the best and most optimal one is just find max and min values, divide by my step (50 in this case) and then do loop checking all the values and assigning to appropriate group.

Is there any other, better approach for that?

Comment: You can pass a range of buckets to `pd.cut` to group them

Comment: What are the criteria for the bucket size/spacing?

Comment: @Alex There isn't any specific criteria. The spacing can be 10 or 100 as well. I have really big number of similar values and I just want to decrease it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing the following, assuming your value column is labeled `val`

```
import numpy as np
df['bin'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: 50*np.floor(x/50))
```

The result is the following:

```
df.groupby('bin')['val'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to EdChum [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463019/grouping-numerical-values-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment64330006_38463019) and based on [this](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_binning_data.html) example I've figured out, the best way (at least for me) is to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

step = 50

#...

max_val = df.distance.max()
bins = list(range(0,int(np.ceil(max_val/step))*step+step,step))
clusters = pd.cut(df.distance,bins,labels=bins[1:])
```